# TypeError: Cannot Read properties of undefined (reading 'close')

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i'm trying to close connection with database after getting data in an asynchronous function but i get Error from mongoose.disconnect function , i tried to read the docs and some articls about mongoose but i didn't find any solution to my issue

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dbURL= 'mongodb://localhost:27017/chat-app';
const User = mongoose.model("user",userShema);

const getFriendRequests = async () =>{
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(dbURL);
        let data = await User.find();
        mongoose.disconnect();
        return data
    } catch(err) {
        mongoose.disconnect();
        throw new Error(err)
    }
}
```

the Error shown in terminal

[image]

Comment: Does your data retrieval succeeds? Is the error thrown from `mongoose.disconnect` in the `try` or in the `catch`?

Comment: in the try , if i remove mongoose.disconnect from the try , the error won't be shown